# Copy all the column data of a collection except one into another collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have one collection sample document is here

```
 {
  "name" : "1234567890",
  "mobile" : "Test",
  "user_id":1
}
```

Output collection document format

```
"test_column" :  {
  "name" : "1234567890",
  "mobile" : "Test"
}
```

My requirement is to copy all column of collection into `test_column` exclude `user_id`.

I am using below query but it copies all the columns but I want to exclude one

```
db.collectionname.aggregate(([{"$project":{"test_column":"$$ROOT"}}{"$out":tempCollection}]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another `$project` stage to exclude `user_id`:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
    {  "$project":{ "test_column":"$$ROOT" }},
    {  "$project":{ "test_column.user_id": 0 }},
    {  "$out": tempCollection }
    ]
);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_ABDJXuu6cZ)